# Visual Leak Detector Does Not Print

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, visual-leak-detector

I am trying to detect memory leaks in a C++ application which is a server always listens for requests and never exit using Visual Leak Detector but it does not print any thing to the Visual Studio output window only prints 'Visual Leak Detector Version 2.4RC2 installed.' i also tried to log output to a file and did not work also

Comment: It seems to me that VLD prints only once the program has exited, but maybe you set it up in an other way ?

Comment: I have tried to make the program to exit after receiving request and configured VLD to log in a file and print in the output window and also it did not work

Comment: Then there probably are not any leaks. Although I would verify with a small 10 line console application that VLD is working properly. I mean create a program with a main() and leak memory on purpose and verify that vld is working. Make sure you include vld.h.

Comment: I tried to make a small code and it worked and detected leaks, and tried to create  leaks in my application and it did not detect it